# On creating a new bank account for "sugar payments"

Tags: bank-account, scams, online-payment, sugar-daddy

Recently, I became a sugar baby and found a daddy who wants me to create a new bank account for him to send money to. He doesn’t want to use a cash app because he has been scammed in the past.

1. Is this a scam?
2. Is it normal to create a new bank account?
3. Would he be able to see my location?

Comment: There are a number of similar questions you can find for more detailed answers, but yes it's a scam. If they wanted to send you money they would do so in one of the many conventional methods rather than having you jump through hoops. Typically they'd send some money, ask you to send some back or buy gift cards or some other BS, and then you'd find the deposit into your new account was reversed and you'd be out whatever you sent them.

Comment: The irony "He has been scrammed in the past" while he tries to scam you. Tell him he can mail a check. I betcha he will find an excuse why he can't do that either.

Comment: @Hart CO: Not to mention the obvious point that nobody wants to send you money unless they expect to get something in return.  If the OP's lucky, it'd be a real sugar daddy relationship, and they'd both get some mutually-enjoyable sex out of the deal.  Otherwise, it's a scam.

Answer (score 8):

Any such deal that doesn’t involve cash payments is a scam. Zero exceptions. There is absolutely no way a genuine sugar daddy would need you to create an account. And I don’t know what you think a sugar daddy wants you for, but it involves meeting you and exchanging services for cash.